# Is there a way to universally apply a controller function to all routes in a router file in express?

Tags: javascript, express

I have the code below in an application. Let's say I wanted each "router.get" instance to use "authController.isLoggedIn". Is there a way to do that which wouldn't require me to type it out 6 different times? I was thinking router.use might be it... but after doing some research, I don't think that's right anymore. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
router.get('/tour/:slug', viewsController.getTour);
router.get('/login', authController.isLoggedIn, viewsController.getLoginForm);
router.get('/signup', authController.isLoggedIn, viewsController.getSignupForm);
router.get('/me', authController.protect, viewsController.getAccount);
router.get('/my-tours', authController.protect, viewsController.getMyTours);
router.get('/create', authController.protect, viewsController.createTour);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
const authRouter = (path, param, ...controllers) =>
  router.get(path, authController[param], ...controllers);

router.get('/tour/:slug', viewsController.getTour);
authRouter('/login', 'isLoggedIn', viewsController.getLoginForm);
authRouter('/signup', 'isLoggedIn', viewsController.getSignupForm);
authRouter('/me', 'protect', viewsController.getAccount);
authRouter('/my-tours', 'protect', viewsController.getMyTours);
authRouter('/create', 'protect', viewsController.createTour);
```